# Android : Not able to find the reason of NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, logcat

I am working on a form in android where I render values of one dropdown by selecting the value of another dropdown which is placed on top of current drop down.
So here I am selecting one University from University dropdown and on select I am rendering the values of Institutions and adding them to institution dropdown then I am selecting one Institution from Institution dropdown.
Till here everything is fine but after that if I am again changing the University then app is crashing.
Problem is, in logcat it is showing `NullPointerException` but it is not showing the line number where it is crashing or cause of crashing.

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:548)
    at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:496)
    at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:460)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1470)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1670)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1528)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1441)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14243)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4490)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1181)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4942)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EducationalSchoolCollege.java

```
public class EducationalSchoolCollege extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RadioGroup rg__educational_type;
    private RadioButton radioeduButton;
    Spinner university,instituition,degree,stream,tenureType,tenureLevel,cycleSpinner;
    String student_uuid,student_name,email_id,selectedTypeIs="";

    Map<String,String> educationSubmitMapData = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> universityListMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> instituteListMap = new HashMap<>();


    List<String> universityList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> instituteList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> degreeList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> streamList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> tenureTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> tenureLevelList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> cycleList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> universityNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> instituteNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> degreeNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> streamNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> tenureNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> tenureLevelNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> cycleNameList = new ArrayList<>();


    String university_uuid,institute_uuid,degree_uuid,stream_uuid,tenure_uuid,tenure_level_uuid,cycle_uuid,degree_name;
    Button submitEducationalBtn;
    SharedPreferences afterClassPref;
    AfterClassApp controller;
    public ProgressDialog progdialog;
    TextView clickHereId;
    String fromProfile = "",genreic_user="";
    //avinash
   // TextView textView4;
    TextView degreeText,streamText,tenureText,cycleText;
    EditText edt_instituition_other;
    boolean selectedIsOther=false;
    boolean isCheckedRadio = false;
    //avinash

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.educational_school_college);

        controller = (AfterClassApp) getApplicationContext();
        afterClassPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        student_uuid = afterClassPref.getString("studentUUID", null);
        student_name = afterClassPref.getString("studentName", null);
        email_id = afterClassPref.getString("studentEmail", null);

        university = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.university);
        instituition = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.instituition);
        degree = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.degree);
        stream = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stream);
        tenureType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tenure);
        tenureLevel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tenureLevel);
        cycleSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cycle);
        submitEducationalBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitEducationalBtn);
        clickHereId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clickHereId);

        //avinash
        edt_instituition_other = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_instituition_other);
        degreeText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.degreeText);
        streamText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.streamText);
        tenureText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tenureText);
        cycleText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cycleText);

       // textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        rg__educational_type = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg__educational_type);

        clickHereId.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            rg__educational_type.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
        }

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("from_profile")){
                fromProfile = extras.getString("from_profile");
            }
            if (extras.containsKey("genreic_user")){
                genreic_user = extras.getString("genreic_user");
            }

        }

        //G Analytics
        if (!Constants.IS_EMAIL_EXIT) {
            Tracker tracker = ((AfterClassApp) getApplication()).getTracker(AfterClassApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            tracker.setScreenName("MyAfterClass EducationalSchoolCollege");
            tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
        }

        rg__educational_type.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


                int selectedId = rg__educational_type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                radioeduButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                instituition.setAdapter(null);
                degree.setAdapter(null);
                stream.setAdapter(null);
                tenureType.setAdapter(null);
                tenureLevel.setAdapter(null);
                cycleSpinner.setAdapter(null);
                if(radioeduButton.getText().toString().equals("School")){
                    edt_instituition_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isCheckedRadio = true;
                    clickHereId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setAdapter(university,universityNameList);
                    universityList.clear();
                    instituteList.clear();
                    degreeList.clear();
                    streamList.clear();
                    tenureTypeList.clear();
                    tenureLevelList.clear();
                    cycleList.clear();

                    universityNameList.clear();
                    instituteNameList.clear();
                    degreeNameList.clear();
                    streamNameList.clear();
                    tenureNameList.clear();
                    tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                    cycleNameList.clear();
                    firstTimeSchoolUserData("university",null,null,null,null);
                    selectedTypeIs = "board";
                    degreeText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    degree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stream.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tenureType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cycleSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    streamText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tenureText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cycleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }
                if(radioeduButton.getText().toString().equals("College")){
                    edt_instituition_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isCheckedRadio = true;
                    if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(genreic_user)){
                        clickHereId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                        clickHereId.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    setAdapter(university,universityNameList);
                    universityList.clear();
                    instituteList.clear();
                    degreeList.clear();
                    streamList.clear();
                    tenureTypeList.clear();
                    tenureLevelList.clear();
                    cycleList.clear();

                    universityNameList.clear();
                    instituteNameList.clear();
                    degreeNameList.clear();
                    streamNameList.clear();
                    tenureNameList.clear();
                    tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                    cycleNameList.clear();
                    firstTimeUserData("university", null, null,null,null,null,null,null);
                    selectedTypeIs = "college";
                    degreeText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    degree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    stream.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tenureType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cycleSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    streamText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tenureText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cycleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });
        // avinash



        clickHereId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(EducationalSchoolCollege.this, OtherFirstTimeEducational.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

//        setAdapter(university,universityList);
//        firstTimeUserData("university",null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        university.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String seluniversity = (String) university.getSelectedItem();
                instituteList.clear();;
                degreeList.clear();
                streamList.clear();
                tenureTypeList.clear();
                tenureLevelList.clear();
                cycleList.clear();

                instituteNameList.clear();;
                degreeNameList.clear();
                streamNameList.clear();
                tenureNameList.clear();
                tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                cycleNameList.clear();
                Log.d("UNI ","seluniversity "+ seluniversity+ " pos:: "+position);
//                clear on proper selecting



                //                clear on proper selecting

                if ("board".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedTypeIs)){
                    //Todo
                    university_uuid = universityListMap.get(seluniversity);
                    firstTimeSchoolUserData("institute",university_uuid,null,null,null);
                }else{
                    if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(seluniversity)){
                        university_uuid = universityList.get(position-1);
                        educationSubmitMapData.put("university_uuid",university_uuid);
                        Log.d("UNI ", "university_uuid "+university_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserInstitutionData("institute",university_uuid);
                        firstTimeUserData("institute",university_uuid,null,null,null,null,null,null);
                    }else{
                        university_uuid = null;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        instituition.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String selInstitute = (String) instituition.getSelectedItem();
                degreeList.clear();
                streamList.clear();
                tenureTypeList.clear();
                tenureLevelList.clear();
                cycleList.clear();

                degreeNameList.clear();
                streamNameList.clear();
                tenureNameList.clear();
                tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                cycleNameList.clear();

                if ("board".equalsIgnoreCase(selectedTypeIs)) {
                    //Todo
                    institute_uuid = instituteListMap.get(selInstitute);
                    if ("other".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)){
                        // TODO: Hide edittext box and show here
                        edt_instituition_other.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        selectedIsOther=true;
                    }else{
                        selectedIsOther=false;
                        edt_instituition_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    tenureLevelList.clear();
                    firstTimeSchoolUserData("tenure_level", university_uuid, institute_uuid, null, null);
                } else {
                    if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)) {
//            int position = university.getSelectedItemPosition();
                        if(instituteList.size()==0){
                            return;
                        }
                        edt_instituition_other.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        institute_uuid = instituteList.get(position - 1);
                        educationSubmitMapData.put("institute_uuid", institute_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserDegreeData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid);
                        firstTimeUserData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid, null, null, null, null, null);
                    } else {
                        institute_uuid = null;
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        degree.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String selInstitute = (String) degree.getSelectedItem();
                streamList.clear();
                tenureTypeList.clear();
                tenureLevelList.clear();
                cycleList.clear();

                streamNameList.clear();
                tenureNameList.clear();
                tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                cycleNameList.clear();
                if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)){
//            int position = university.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if(degreeList.size()==0){
                        return;
                    }
                    degree_uuid = degreeList.get(position-1);
                    degree_name = degreeNameList.get(position-1);
//                    Log.d("degree_name",""+degree_name);
                    educationSubmitMapData.put("degree_uuid",degree_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserDegreeData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid);
                    firstTimeUserData("stream",university_uuid,institute_uuid,degree_uuid,null,null,null,null);
                }else{
                    degree_uuid = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        stream.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String selInstitute = (String) stream.getSelectedItem();
                tenureTypeList.clear();
                tenureLevelList.clear();
                cycleList.clear();

                tenureNameList.clear();
                tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                cycleNameList.clear();
                if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)){
//            int position = university.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if(streamList.size()==0){
                        return;
                    }
                    stream_uuid = streamList.get(position-1);
                    educationSubmitMapData.put("stream_uuid",stream_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserDegreeData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid);
                    firstTimeUserData("tenure_type",university_uuid,institute_uuid,degree_uuid,stream_uuid,null,null,null);
                }else{
                    stream_uuid = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {




            }
        });

        tenureType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String selInstitute = (String) tenureType.getSelectedItem();
                tenureLevelList.clear();
                cycleList.clear();

                tenureLevelNameList.clear();
                cycleNameList.clear();
                if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)){
//            int position = university.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if(tenureTypeList.size()==0){
                        return;
                    }
                    tenure_uuid = tenureTypeList.get(position-1);
                    educationSubmitMapData.put("tenure_type",tenure_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserDegreeData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid);
                    firstTimeUserData("tenure_level",university_uuid,institute_uuid,degree_uuid,stream_uuid,tenure_uuid,null,null);
                }else{
                    tenure_uuid = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        tenureLevel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String selInstitute = (String) tenureLevel.getSelectedItem();
                cycleList.clear();

                cycleNameList.clear();
                if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)){
//            int position = university.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if(tenureLevelList.size()==0){
                        return;
                    }
                    tenure_level_uuid = tenureLevelList.get(position-1);
                    educationSubmitMapData.put("tenure_level",tenure_level_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserDegreeData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid);
                    firstTimeUserData("cycle",university_uuid,institute_uuid,degree_uuid,stream_uuid,tenure_uuid,tenure_level_uuid,null);
                }else{
                    tenure_level_uuid = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

        cycleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String selInstitute = (String) cycleSpinner.getSelectedItem();
                if (!"Select".equalsIgnoreCase(selInstitute)){
//            int position = university.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    if(cycleList.size()==0){
                        return;
                    }
                    cycle_uuid = cycleList.get(position-1);
                    educationSubmitMapData.put("cycle",cycle_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserDegreeData("degree", university_uuid, institute_uuid);
//                    firstTimeUserData("cycle",university_uuid,institute_uuid,degree_uuid,stream_uuid,tenure_uuid,cycle_uuid,null);
                }else{
                    cycle_uuid = null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do `spinner.setAdapter(null);` Instead of this you can use `mySpinner.setEnabled(false)` . Although its not same but you have to compromise

Comment: Can you tell me what I can put instead of these line?

Comment: use spinner.setEnabled(false) instead of spinner.setAdapter(null) this will not allow anything to be selected from the spinner.

Comment: This is not solving the problem, now on select of university, institutions are rendering in second dropdown but I am not able to select institution because Institution dropdown is looking disable.

Comment: So do not call setEnabled(false) on your institution spinner

Comment: I am putting null because I want to reset the value of all fields. Can you tell me some way to reset the values of all fields.

Comment: You can do spinner.setSelection(0); this will remove the current selection from the spinner and select the initial position. If you are trying to update the values displayed in the list, you first have to update the data in the adapter and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Is it possible to set spinner empty?

Comment: One indirect method(not recommended) can be spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter()) in the adapter your data list should be empty. Another way can be in your adapter create a method to update the data list. update the data list there with an empty list and do notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException occurs because you set adapter is null.  Remove setAdapter(null) in Spinner.

```
            instituition.setAdapter(null);
            degree.setAdapter(null);
            stream.setAdapter(null);
            tenureType.setAdapter(null);
            tenureLevel.setAdapter(null);
            cycleSpinner.setAdapter(null);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I can put instead of these line?

Comment: why you have setAdapter(null)? i mean whats the reason?

Comment: I am putting null because I want to reset the value of all fields.

Comment: spinner.getAdapter().clear(); 
spinner.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: This is not working, clear and notifyDataSetChanged are not coming in the case of spinner.